# Not getting a refresh token from Auth0.authorize() - PKCE

Tags: auth0, openid-connect

I have a native app in Auth0, using the PKCE flow. When I call `Auth0.authorize()` from my Ionic app, using Auth0.js, I’m getting an access token and an ID token, but no refresh token.

I am passing the `offline_access` scope to Auth0.authorize() (as well as `openid profile`). The API I’m using has “`Allow Offline Access`” enabled. I have no rules defined.

The app in Auth0 has the following grants enabled in the advanced settings: Implicit, Authorization Code, Refresh Token.

In my config for Auth0 in my client app, I’m setting:

```
...,
audience: 'xxxxxxxxx', /* My API identifier */
responseType: 'token id_token'
```

My redirect callback is receiving hash params like:
`access_token=xxxxx&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer&state=xxx&id_token=xxxxx` but no refresh_token.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If response type is `id_token token` and `scope` includes `openid`, this is an OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol with implicit flow as the authentication path. In this case no refresh token is issued.

From [OIDC Core](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication) spec:

> Authentication can follow one of three paths: the Authorization Code
>   Flow (`response_type=code`), the Implicit Flow (`response_type=id_token token` 
>   or `response_type=id_token`), or the Hybrid Flow ...

Hybrid flow requires that `response_type` has `code` as the first word. Thus, you're in Implicit flow territory. By the OIDC spec, Authorization Code and Hybrid flows issue a refresh token, Implicit flow does not.